# Swift Firebase Reuse a function throughout the app

Tags: swift, function, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, in a few places I am loading data from Firebase Firestore database and showing the data. The problem is I am not adopting the DRY technique and I know I shouldn't, but I am reusing this same load function in different places in my app.

```
func loadData() {

        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        db.collection("users").document((user?.uid)!).collection("children").getDocuments() {
            QuerySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                // get all children into an array
                self.childArray = QuerySnapshot!.documents.flatMap({Child(dictionary: $0.data())})
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.childrenTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The function simply grabs all the children from the database and adds them to my child array.

Is there some better way to do this or a central place I can put this function where it can be called as and when I need it in the app instead of repeatedly adding it in multiple view controllers?

I thought about a helper class, and just calling the function, but then not sure how to add the result to the childArray in the viewcontroller I needed it?

---

my Child model

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore


protocol DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}

// Child Struct
struct Child {

    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var timestamp: Date
    var imageURL: String

    var dictionary:[String:Any] {
        return [
            "name":name,
            "age":age,
            "timestamp":timestamp,
            "imageURL":imageURL
        ]
    }

}

//Child Extension
extension Child : DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let  name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
            let age = dictionary["age"] as? Int,
            let  imageURL = dictionary["imageURL"] as? String,
            let timestamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as? Date else {
                return nil
        }
        self.init(name: name, age: age, timestamp: timestamp, imageURL: imageURL)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I have updated to safely unwrap the optionals.  You may still have to modify as I am not sure what your Firebase structure is, nor do I know your Child initializer.

You could just write this as a static function and then reuse it everywhere.  I assume you might have some class related to whatever "children" is, and that'd be the best place to implement.  You could pass the results (as an option array of `Child`) in a completion handler so that you can do whatever you need with those results.  It'd look something like this:

```
static func loadData(_ completion: (_ children: [Child]?)->()) {

    guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { completion(nil); return }
    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.uid).collection("children").getDocuments() {
        querySnapshot, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(nil)
        } else {
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else { completion(nil); return }
            // get all children into an array
            let children = snapshot.documents.flatMap({Child(dictionary: $0.data())})
            completion(children)
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming you have this implemented in your Child class you would use it like this:

```
Child.loadData { (children) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let loadedChildren = children {
            //Do whatever you need with the children
            self.childArray = loadedChildren
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @creeperspeak thank you for kindly responding! Your suggestion seems perfect! I have implemented the code, however, I get a Fatal Error stating: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value this is showing in the Static Function Section. I will add a screenshot to the main post.

Comment: OK, yes, I did not update your code to safely unwrap everything.  I will update it now.

Comment: Oh, ok.  The crash is likely because your `var db: Firestore!` has never been properly set.  You need to make sure you have a pointer to that db.

Comment: Ahh ok, I will need to figure out how to do that, not used a pointer before. so the code you suggested will work then and wont need unwrapping? - sorry just saw your edit ;)

Comment: I updated my code again.  All you need to do is use `Firestore.firestore()` instead of `db`.

Comment: Of course! ha ha awesome @creeperspeak you absolute legend! Thank you! you have really helped make a massive difference to my app, thank you!